# How to fix an angular.module not working with dependent modules?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, angularjs-module

I'm pretty clear on how angular.module works, but this eludes me for whatever reason.

In my code I have the following

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", [])

app.controller("MainCtrl", ...)
```

but my code only works when there is no array for dependent modules, like this:

```
     var app = angular.module("myApp"); 
     app.controller("MainCtrl",...)
```

I haven't the slightest the clue as to what would cause the problem, as I've always understood the need for the empty array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I've always understood the need for the empty array

Array as the second argument is only needed when the module is created. So with

```
angular.module("myApp", [])
```

you create new module. And with

```
angular.module("myApp")
```

you retrieve already existent module which was previously created.

> my code only works when there is no array for dependent modules

It means that you have already created module `myApp`. In this case you don't have to recreate it again, as it will erase all previously registered controllers, etc.

Comment: that's weird. I'm using this controller to create the module to begin with...I guess not. I guess I'll have to figure out where it was already created. Thanks!